# No specularity when rendered?

Tags: light

I am learning Blender by play around with the default startup scene, where there is a cube, a camera, and a point light source.

I then only did one thing: I increased `Material -> Specular -> Intensity` from 0.5 to 1.0.

Then I render the scene. Although the material preview shows some specularity, the rendered image doesn't show any specularity.

[image]

Why is this, and how may I fix it?

Comment: Try to render with a sphere instead.

Comment: or use cube as material preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preview is a sphere, and the scene is a cube. They don't have the same reflections, and that's pretty normal, when you think about it... Did you ever see a box with absolutely so bevel on the edges (that's pretty hard to find) with absolutely the same reflections as a ball? This reflection dot is essentially created by the curve of the sphere. If you want to see the material test on a cube, there are a bunch of buttons at the right of the material test window. They define the shape on which the preview will be made.